# NHibernate: Cannot insert null exception when storing a new object

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying a very basic example with NHibernate but get an exception on session.Save() call.
Here is my model:

```
public class Student
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }

        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is Student.hbm.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 

<hibernate-mapping xmlns = "urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly = "NHibernateDemoApp" namespace = "NHibernateDemoApp">

    <class name = "Student"> 
        <id name = "ID">
            <generator class = "native"/> 
        </id> 

        <property name = "LastName"/> 
        <property name = "FirstMidName"/> 
    </class> 

</hibernate-mapping>
```

This the code to save an entity:

```
using (ISession session = this.sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    savedEntity = (Student) session.Save(new Student { ID = 1, FirstMidName = "Test first name", LastName = "Test Last name"});

                    try
                    {
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (!transaction.WasCommitted)
                        {
                            transaction.Rollback();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

It fails with the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table
>   'NHibernateDemoDB.dbo.Student'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails.

What's wrong here?

Comment: native means it's using an Identity on the server side for SQL Server.  Is your ID column defined as Identity in the table definition?

Comment: Thanks for replies. Looks like my table was created incorrectly. I recreated it and now it works.

Comment: Great that you have found the solution.
I'd like to point out something else however:  You should not assign a value to the ID property yourself if the DB will assign one.  It is better to have a private setter on the ID property.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels Yes, I understand it. I was just debugging and set the value of Id by my-self to check if it will save it. Now I removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated my table with the following script and now it works:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] (
    [ID] INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [FirstMidName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Student] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
```